# Salary formatted incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, internationalization

The format of salary appears to be hardcoded. It's nice that you decided to display salaries in my local currency (and list jobs based on my current location), but the format should also be local (based on my Web Browser = HTTP `Accept-Language` header).
Currently it is a bit confusing and requires additional brain cycles.

Current situation:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

This may seem like a small improvement, but from Usability standpoint it is quite important.
For instance, please keep in mind that in Polish, French and German locale comma is a decimal separator. That is, zł5,400 (around $1500) means 5.4 zł (around $1.5). I don't think I'm interested (not even per hour) ;)

Comment: Suggestion: Why make the web site determine how to display the amount properly? Let the job owner entering the currency and amount also choose thousands and decimal currency separators for each currency used (perhaps even at the profile level, not the per-job level). Problem solved. There also might be some other customizations needed: currency symbol before or after the number, how many decimal places to display (if any), how many digits are between "thousands" separators.

Comment: Downvoting... no thick red freehand circles. Thin neat rectangles don't cut it enough ;)

Answer (score -16):

stackoverflow.com is not localized - i.e. it's always in English. This is a conscious decision *for the moment*. We'll consider localization of the jobs tab at some point in the future.

Thanks for the report.

Comment: All the german's and french are downvoting lol.  No on a serious note, it's probably the reason why so has different sites for russia, china, etc.  I'd only expect the jobs to probably not obey other countries - as bad as that sounds, internationalization is not an easy task.

Comment: If it's not localized, why change the currency symbol? Changing the currency but not formatting the currency properly is a disconnect that should *not* be by-design.

Comment: @Chris Currency is selected by the employer when they enter the salary details. So it's not localized.

Comment: Whether it's an internal conversion or an end-user selecting the currency, it's already partially localized. That's the disconnect I'm referring to.  Any user who doesn't understand this disconnect is going to be confused.  Until this feature is fully implemented, perhaps some sort of explanation or disclaimer should appear on the jobs when viewing non-default currency/locale?  In this case it was found by a user who understands that disconnect and raised the issue here on meta, but there are likely others out there that don't understand.

Comment: @Chris how do you define non-default currency / locale? The end user sees what the job poster entered and its displayed in English format because, well, SO is in English.

Comment: @Chris: I mostly agree with you, but changing the currency seems massively more important than changing the rest of the localization: "zl5,000 - 14,000" is confusing and hard-to-read, but "$5,000 - 14,000" would be a major lie . . .

Comment: possible stop gap solution might be putting a space between the currency type and the value?  I realize this is not perfect, but it would make your output read like so, zl 5,000 - 14,000 or in the case of USD, $ 5,000 - 14,000.  This isn't quite as expected per OP, but it's at least a bit more readable, and wouldn't require specific on the fly formatting based on locale.

Comment: @DeanWard - any currency/locale that isn't USD$/English is non-default.  Apologies for my lack of clarity - I understand it's a complex issue, and I'm merely trying to propose some rough ideas that seem low-cost for mitigating user confusion. I don't pretend to know all the details or how to implement it here, but IMO this seems like something that shouldn't just be swept under the rug as 'by design'.  However, as I understand it, that's completely your call to make, and this is probably rather low on the priority scale :)

Comment: @Chris please don't feel we're sweeping this under the rug! I want to do *something* I'm just not sure of the correct approach here... E.g. currencies in English speaking countries are numerous; CAD, GBP, EUR, USD. Even currencies used in the multiple locales might have specific rendering requirements! Number formatting across the rest of SO uses English. On Careers we use the user's language (French, German, UK and US English), but for the new Jobs tab we're currently **only** using English. Hence the difficulty and the by-design tag... We're still thinking on it.

Comment: Why make the web site determine how to display the currency separator? Let the job owner entering the currency also choose thousands and decimal currency separators. Problem solved.